# Grayscale image with color cutout

Tags: css

Is it possible to use css to adjust the image in grayscale and make a cutout containing the original colors at a specific position? Something like as on attached image..
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcQoe.jpg)

Comment: I gave you a solution with no image duplication. Also the other solution is using clip which is deprecated (clip-path should be used like I did)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another way of doing it without pseudo-elements but with help of the [clip](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_clip.asp) property:

```css
.image-container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.image-grey {
  display: block;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}

.image-color {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  clip: rect(50px, 250px, 200px, 150px);
}
```

```html
 <div class="image-container">
  <img
    class="image-grey"
    src="https://source.unsplash.com/300x300/?green"
  />
  <img
    class="image-color"
    src="https://source.unsplash.com/300x300/?green"
  />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using pseudo element and clip-path you can do it:

```css
.box {
  height:300px;
  position:relative;
}
.box::before,
.box::after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background:url(https://picsum.photos/id/127/800/800) center/cover;
}
.box::before {
  filter:grayscale(1); /* the bottom layer with a filter*/
}
.box::after {
  clip-path:inset(20% 50px  50px  50%); /* the top layer clipped */
  /*             (top left bottom right)*/
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```